# SharePoint Search REST API does not return custom columns values

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, document-library, spfx, sharepoint-rest-api

I've been trying to use SharePoint REST API to retrieve a number of files on my site but for some reason, if it does tell me the name or descriptions of the files, it returns null for every single custom columns I have for those files.

Here's the code I use:

```
const path = "Path:" + AppState.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + "/* ";
const url = AppState.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='" + path + "IsDocument:true'&selectproperties='Status,Title,Path,Created,Description,MGS_Hierarchy'";
```

and here are the example of a result:

[image: Results of the query]

As you can see, the "Status" and "MGS_Hierarchy" values are null, even tough they are set in the list:

[image]

The two columns are inherited from a custom content type. I don't know if it changes something.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just confirming. Are those custom site columns added to document library? Are you using correct managed property names for columns?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the **managed property** names for the custom columns to retrieve custom column values using SharePoint Search REST API.

Make sure you are using correct **managed property** names for the custom columns.

You can find the managed property names from **Search Schema** in site settings.

Follow below links for more information:

1. [How to Identify Custom Property Names in SharePoint](https://support.shortpoint.com/support/solutions/articles/1000304547-how-to-identify-custom-property-names-in-sharepoint)
2. [SharePoint Search REST API overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview)

Comment: This doesn't tell a person how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

during my test i had the same issue and i found out that the way to retrieve these fields is by putting them in the query, try changing your query to this

```
(IsDocument:true) AND (MGS_Hierarchy:*)
```

Doing this will bring them.

Be warned that on another site we had a similar issue but the search was being compromise because we had different list that some did not have the field added, and this query was for some reason only bringing the items who had this column so we changed the query to

```
(IsDocument:true) OR (MGS_Hierarchy:*)
```

And this time it got all the documents but the ones who did not have the field added the value was null.

If someone has a better way please let me know i am also interested in this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by using `postquery` instead of query. `postquery` uses Post and you have to add the managed propriety name to the `SelectProperties`. More information at: [SharePoint Search REST API overview - Post requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224#post-requests)

Remember to add the field to the manage proprieties search schema. I added mine under the search schema under the site level, I couldn't find the field under the tenant level. (site setting->Site Collection Administration-> Search Schema -> New Managed Property )